# Checking if dictionary keys are being entered

Tags: python

Is there a more efficient way to check if what the user has entered **(“food_ordered”)** is on the **“order_menu”** without having to use **“food_keys”** or **“food_names”**?

```
order_menu = {("C", "Chips (Scoops)") : 2.80, ("F", "Fish (Battered)") : 2.90, ("Fc", "Fish (Crumbed)") : 4.90, ("Fib", "Filet (Battered)") : 6.90, ("Fic", "Filet (Crumbed)") : 6.90, 
         ("Hd", "Hot Dog") : 2.60, ("S", "Sausage") : 2.60, ("Mp" , "Meat Patty (Homemade)") : 3.90, ("Cr", "Crabstick") : 2.50, ("Sr", "Spring Roll (Homemade)") : 2.80, 
         ("Cr", "Curry Roll (Homemade)"): 2.80, ("Pof", "Potato Fritter (Homemade)") : 1.20, ("Paf", "Paua Fritter (Homemade)") : 5.90, ("Cn", "Chicken Nugget") : 1, 
         ("Mh", "Mini Hot Dog (On a stick)") : 1.20, ("Pf", "Pineapple Fritter") : 2.50}
order_dictionary = {}

food_keys = []
food_names = []
for (food_key, food_name), price in order_menu.items():
    food_keys.append(food_key)
    food_names.append(food_name)

    
def order():
    for food_name, price in order_menu.items():
        print(f"• {food_name[1]:<35} {'('+ food_name[0] + ')': <10} ${price:.2f} each")    
    while True:
        food_ordered = input("Order: (Type 'End' when you have finished) ").title()
        if food_ordered == "End" and len(order_dictionary) > 0:
            break
        elif food_ordered in food_keys or food_ordered in food_names:
            for (key, food_name), price in order_menu.items():
                if food_ordered == key:
                    food_ordered = food_name 
            while True:
                try:
                    quantity_food = int(input("Number of {}: ".format(food_ordered)))
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please input NUMBERS only.")                
            if quantity_food > 10:
                quantity_food_check = int(input("Are you sure you want x{} {}? (re-enter to confirm): ".format(quantity_food, food_ordered)))
                order_dictionary[food_ordered] = quantity_food
            else:
                order_dictionary[food_ordered] = quantity_food
        else:
            print("Please enter an actual item on the menu!")    

order()
```

Comment: You should try https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: For starters, I'd recommend you make food_keys and food_names into sets, instead of lists: Looking for a value in a list is O(n), while looking for a key in a set or a dict is O(1)

Comment: Have the key for your dictionary be the abbreviation only.  Have a separate dictionary that maps the full name into the abbreviation.  Now, you can do your searches by looking in the dicts.  Dict lookup is much more efficient than list lookup.

Comment: Time is probably better spent ensuring the interface is as user-friendly as possible since any performance increase will be unnoticeable in this application.  Meaning, shaving off milliseconds will go unnoticed, but was bothered that entering "End" didn't work if I hadn't entered any menu items yet (i.e. change my mind and didn't want to order anything).   See [HE FALLACY OF PREMATURE OPTIMIZATION](https://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451)

Comment: You could use numbers as keys... just like Big Smoke in GTA SA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. There are many ways to do it. I suggest using numbers as keys in `order_menu` nested dict and iterate over it. The user only input the reference number of food name, just like Big Smoke in GTA SA.

Some problems in your code has been noticed in others comment. Here some changes to your code without restructuring it. Conditional handling to some bugs have been added to the code. (See inline comment)

**Suggested**

```
# Change order_menu dict to nested dict with numbers as key
order_menu = {1: {"Chips (Scoops)": 2.80},
              2: {"Fish (Battered)": 2.90},
              3: {"Fish (Crumbed)": 4.90},
              4: {"Filet (Battered)": 6.90},
              5: {"Filet (Crumbed)": 6.90},
              6: {"Hot Dog": 2.60},
              7: {"Sausage": 2.60},
              8: {"Meat Patty (Homemade)": 3.90},
              9: {"Crabstick": 2.50},
              10: {"Spring Roll (Homemade)": 2.80},
              11: {"Curry Roll (Homemade)": 2.80},
              12: {"Potato Fritter (Homemade)": 1.20},
              13: {"Paua Fritter (Homemade)": 5.90},
              14: {"Chicken Nugget": 1.00},
              15: {"Mini Hot Dog (On a stick)": 1.20},
              16: {"Pineapple Fritter": 2.50}
              }

order_dictionary = {}


def order():
    for idx, food in order_menu.items():
        for food_names, price in food.items():
            print(f"{idx:<4} {food_names: <27} ${price:.2f} each")  # print value of nested dict
    while True:
        food_ordered = input("Order: (Type 'End' when you have finished) ").title()
        if food_ordered == "End":
            if len(order_dictionary) > 0:  # Added more condition when user hasn't input any number
                break
            else:
                exit()
        elif food_ordered.isdigit() and int(food_ordered) in order_menu:  # check if user input is a number and within order_menu
            num = int(food_ordered)
            for item in order_menu[num]:
                food_ordered = item  # get value of numbers as name
            while True:
                try:
                    quantity_food = int(input("Number of {}: ".format(food_ordered)))
                    if quantity_food < 1:
                        print("Please enter a positive number only")  # Add handling when the input is zero or negative number
                        continue
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please input NUMBERS only.")
            if quantity_food > 10:
                quantity_food_check = int(input("Are you sure you want x{} of {}? (re-enter to confirm or enter other number): ".format(quantity_food, food_ordered)))
                quantity_food = quantity_food_check  # overwrite quantity_food value
            # Change the structure of order_dictionary with calculated price
            order_dictionary[food_ordered] = {'quantity': quantity_food, 'price': quantity_food * order_menu[num][food_ordered]}  #removed else
        else:
            print("Please enter an actual item on the menu!")


order()
# Added print for order_dictionary
print('\nYour order:')
for i, pair in enumerate(order_dictionary.items()):
    idx, item = pair
    print(f"{i+1:<3} {idx: <27} {int(item['quantity']): <5} ${item['price']:.2f}")
```

**output**

```
1    Chips (Scoops)              $2.80 each
2    Fish (Battered)             $2.90 each
3    Fish (Crumbed)              $4.90 each
4    Filet (Battered)            $6.90 each
5    Filet (Crumbed)             $6.90 each
6    Hot Dog                     $2.60 each
7    Sausage                     $2.60 each
8    Meat Patty (Homemade)       $3.90 each
9    Crabstick                   $2.50 each
10   Spring Roll (Homemade)      $2.80 each
11   Curry Roll (Homemade)       $2.80 each
12   Potato Fritter (Homemade)   $1.20 each
13   Paua Fritter (Homemade)     $5.90 each
14   Chicken Nugget              $1.00 each
15   Mini Hot Dog (On a stick)   $1.20 each
16   Pineapple Fritter           $2.50 each
Order: (Type 'End' when you have finished) What?
Please enter an actual item on the menu!
Order: (Type 'End' when you have finished) 17
Please enter an actual item on the menu!
Order: (Type 'End' when you have finished) 15
Number of Mini Hot Dog (On a stick): 0
Please enter a positive number only
Number of Mini Hot Dog (On a stick): 3
Order: (Type 'End' when you have finished) 6
Number of Hot Dog: -1
Please enter a positive number only
Number of Hot Dog: 2
Order: (Type 'End' when you have finished) 7
Number of Sausage: 13
Are you sure you want x13 of Sausage? (re-enter to confirm or enter other number): 9
Order: (Type 'End' when you have finished) 11
Number of Curry Roll (Homemade): 15
Are you sure you want x15 of Curry Roll (Homemade)? (re-enter to confirm or enter other number): 15
Order: (Type 'End' when you have finished) End

Your order:
1   Mini Hot Dog (On a stick)   3     $3.60
2   Hot Dog                     2     $5.20
3   Sausage                     9     $23.40
4   Curry Roll (Homemade)       15    $42.00

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I assume you don't have other code (function) to calculate price and items.